# <thead> cannot appear as a child of <div>. when using react material-ui/core

Tags: html, reactjs, react-redux

first time react user (BE learning FE here)

when i try to create my table I am getting these errors, and as a result my table wont populate with the data I am trying to pull in via my API.

the error messages I am getting in the console:

`Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <thead> cannot appear as a child of <div>.`
`Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tbody> cannot appear as a child of <div>.`

my code:

```
        <Paper>
            <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <DCandidateForm />
                </Grid>

                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <TableContainer>
                        <TableHead>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>Mobile</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>Blood Group</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                            {
                                props.dCandidateList.map((record, index) => {
                                    return (<TableRow key={index}>
                                        <TableCell>{record.fullName}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>{record.mobile}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>{record.bloodGroup}</TableCell>
                                    </TableRow>)
                                })
                            }
                        </TableBody>
                    </TableContainer>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Paper>


note: I am using the @material-ui/core package for react. 
Is it a problem with how i am structuring my table?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap it with a `Table`, not just a `TableContainer`. [Example from the docs](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/). The container is just for styling purposes. You still need the `Table` to create the underlying `table` element.

```js
<TableContainer>
  <Table>
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Mobile</TableCell>
        <TableCell>Blood Group</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>

    ...

  </Table>
</TableContainer>
```

Without the `component` prop passed to it, `TableContainer` defaults to a `div` as the wrapping element. This is what's causing your error. The final HTML will end up being:

```
<div>
  <thead>
  ...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  ...
  </tbody>
</div>
```

Which isn't correct syntax for a table.

If you don't need to wrap the table with a different tag (like `Paper` in the example), you could remove the container altogether.